# d3.js Radar Graph - filling in between lines

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to create a fill in between two of these triangles, for example a red fill in between the red and green triangles. Does anybody know how to accomplish this? I have seen another example of a radar graph that I believe does something similar, although I think they create the fill using CSS, not d3...

[image]

solved the above problem with mbostock's answer using radial chart...

**Final Result**
[image]

Comment: Hi, would you be able to share the code you used to create the last chart? I am trying to make something similar and am having quite some difficulties achieving the same result. Your help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don’t need to implement a custom path for this; you can use a [d3.svg.area.radial](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Shapes#wiki-area_radial) path generator. Here’s an example of a stacked radial area chart which you might use to plot cyclical data:

- http://bl.ocks.org/3048740

The implementation is fairly similar to a radar chart, except with a radar chart the scales will be different for each angular point.

Comment: this has been a big help, however I'm stuck on one part. I attached my updated radar chart. My issue is that I'm trying to create one layer that has an outline but no fill. Instead, I somehow get two layers with outlines and only one without. I have also added the code where I attempt to accomplish this. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Thanks Mike. Minor note that in [the code you linked](http://bl.ocks.org/3048740) the declaration of `line` is unused and can be removed, making the sample even simpler.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this, you'll have to merge the two triangles into one path by using a custom path generator. Then you can close the path and fill it. Note that if you want the triangles to have different colours, you need to draw them separately.

You could try to cheat and simply fill the bigger triangle and then put the smaller triangle with a white fill on top of it. Then draw the grid lines. This will only work however if the triangles don't overlap.

Comment: could you elaborate on how to use a custom path generator? thanks

Comment: You can find more information on path generators on [the wiki](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Shapes) (section "Path Data Generators"). For the implementation, just have a look at the source code.

Comment: I've implemented a custom generator [here](http://www.larsko.org/v/euca/), function `varLine`.

Comment: from your source it looks like the code you used to create this custom path is the following: Is this correct?  svg.append("svg:line")
                .attr("y1", y(0))
                .attr("y2", y(0))
                .attr("x1", x(tmin))
                .attr("x2", x(tmax));
            svg.append("svg:line")
                .attr("stroke-dasharray", "10 10")
                .attr("y1", y(-3))
                .attr("y2", y(-3))
                .attr("x1", x(tmin))
                .attr("x2", x(tmax));

Comment: No, the path is generated (as an SVG path of the form "M...", see the other answer) in the `varline(points)` function. The function takes a list of points and computes coordinates for each of them. Sorry the function isn't particularly easy to understand, but I don't have an easier example. As I've said before, looking at the source code for [d3.svg.line](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/blob/master/src/svg/line.js) may make it easier to understand.

Answer (score 0):

As Lars mentioned, you want to create an [SVG Path element](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html#PathData).

Paths are defined by a series of commands in the **d** attribute on the element. You want to start by moving absolutely ("M") to one corner of one of the two triangles. Then you'll want to use the lineto ("L" absolutely, or "l" relatively) to go to each corner of the first triangle. Then move absolutely to the other triangle, and repeat. The "z" at the end closes the path. Set the fill on the path to the desired color.

Here's an example path from the link above for a *single* triangle:

```
<path d="M 100 100 L 300 100 L 200 300 z"/>
```

mbostock uses on paths for the bar charts at http://square.github.com/crossfilter/ if you want to look at this technique in action.

Comment: I'm still a little bit confused as to how you create a fill in between two of them though...could you provide a little bit more explanation? thanks.

Comment: You use a closed path drawing method and apply a fill in CSS.